# How to prove $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

How can the following inequation be proven?

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$$

Comment: This is also a consequence of the [Rearrangement inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

Comment: I think $a,b,c$ should be greater or equal with $0$.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge0$

Compute lhs, divide by two and rearrange.

Answer (score 15):

This is a specific form of [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)

Let $x = (a, b, c)$ and $y = (b, c, a)$ as vectors.

The inequality is $ | \left< x,y \right>| \le \|x\|\|y\|. $ with standard inner product definition.  One neat trick to prove this is using an auxilary parameter $t,$ and expanding $$ \| x+ty \|^2 = 
\left< x+ty,x+ty \right> =  \|x\|^2 + 2 \left< x,y \right>t +\|y\|^2t^2.$$  We know, this being a square, is non-negative.  Therefore, the discriminant of the polynomial in $t$ is less or equal to zero.  Which is $\left< x,y \right>^2 - (\|x\|\|y\|)^2 \le 0.$  Substituting the values for $x$ and $y$ will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-ab)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-2ab+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\geq0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$q := a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca = \frac12 \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}^\top \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & -1\\ -1 & 2 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}}_{=: {\rm L}} \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b \\ c\end{bmatrix}$$

where matrix $\rm L$ is the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) with $3$ vertices, whose (signed) [incidence matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) is

$${\rm C} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \color{blue}{1} & 0\\ 0 & -1 & \color{blue}{1} \\ \color{blue}{1} & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $\rm L = C^\top C$, we obtain the following **sum of squares** (SOS) decomposition

$$2q = (\color{blue}{b} - a)^2 + (\color{blue}{c} - b)^2 + (\color{blue}{a} - c)^2 \geq 0$$

which is the SOS decomposition [proposed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64870/339790) by Mark Bennet. Since matrix $\rm L$ is rank-$2$, a terser SOS decomposition with only $2$ terms can easily be found — say, via the Cholesky decomposition.

Using [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2),

```
Macaulay2, version 1.16
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems, LLLBases, MinimalPrimes, PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra, TangentCone, Truncations

i1 : needsPackage( "SumsOfSquares" );
--loading configuration for package "NumericalAlgebraicGeometry" from file /Users/rodrigo/Library/Application Support/Macaulay2/init-NumericalAlgebraicGeometry.m2
--loading configuration for package "Bertini" from file /Users/rodrigo/Library/Application Support/Macaulay2/init-Bertini.m2
--warning: symbol "Verbosity" in MinimalPrimes.Dictionary is shadowed by a symbol in SemidefiniteProgramming.Dictionary
--  use the synonym MinimalPrimes$Verbosity

i2 : R = QQ[a,b,c];

i3 : q = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - a*b - a*c - b*c 

      2          2                2
o3 = a  - a*b + b  - a*c - b*c + c

o3 : R

i4 : sosPoly solveSOS q

             1    1  2    3        2
o4 = (1)(a - -b - -c)  + (-)(b - c)
             2    2       4

o4 : SOSPoly

i5 : tex o4

o5 = $\texttt{SOSPoly}\left\{\texttt{coefficients}\,\Rightarrow\,\left\{1,\,\frac{3}{4}\right\},\,\texttt{generators}\,\Rightarrow\,\left\{a-\frac{1}{2}\,b-\frac{1}{2}\,c,\,b-c\right
     \},\,\texttt{ring}\,\Rightarrow\,R\right\}$
```

In $\TeX$,

$$\texttt{SOSPoly}\left\{\texttt{coefficients}\,\Rightarrow\,\left\{1,\,\frac{3}{4}\right\},\,\texttt{generators}\,\Rightarrow\,\left\{a-\frac{1}{2}\,b-\frac{1}{2}\,c,\,b-c\right\},\,\texttt{ring}\,\Rightarrow\,R\right\}$$

---

[polynomials](/questions/tagged/polynomials) [sum-of-squares-method](/questions/tagged/sum-of-squares-method) [macaulay2](/questions/tagged/macaulay2) [graph-laplacian](/questions/tagged/graph-laplacian)

Answer (score 2):

[Schur](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality) inequality where $r= 0.$

Answer (score 1):

If $\ c> a ,a^2+c^2 \gt 2ac $, because $\ (a-c)^2 \gt 0$
If $\ c>b>a ,c^2+b^2/2+a^2/2 \gt ac+bc $ and $\ b^2/2+a^2/2 \gt ab $, sum of them $\ a^2+b^2+c^2 \gt ab+bc+ac $
If $\ c=b \gt a $ or $\ a=b=c $, it can be solved with same logic.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca\\ 
=(a, b, c)\begin{pmatrix}1&-1/2&-1/2\\-1/2& 1&-1/2\\-1/2&-1/2&1\end{pmatrix}\left(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}\right)$

$=(a, b, c)A\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$

It is sufficient to prove $A$ is a positive semi-definite.

It follows from that the minor determinant of $A$ is one of $1,\dfrac{3}{4},0$

Answer (score 1):

for $a,b,c>=0$
we know $(a-b-c)^2>=0$ 
i.e $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2 (ab + bc + ca) \ge 0$
i.e $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$

Comment: $(a-b-c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab-2ac+2bc$, not $\ldots-2bc$ as you have written.

Answer (score 1):

This inequality can be solved by simple algebra

we have the equation
$$a^2+b^2+c^2 >= ab+ac+cb$$
multiply and divide 2 on both sides
$$\frac{2}{2}(a^2+b^2+c^2) >= \frac{2}{2}(ab+ac+cb)$$
putting the left side equation on the right side
$$\frac{2a^2+2b^2+2c^2 - 2(ab+ac+cb)}{2} >= 0$$
then factorize and multiply by 2 on both the sides
$$\frac{2a^2+2b^2+2c^2 - 2(ab+ac+cb)}{2} >= 0$$
$$\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}{2} >= 0$$
$$\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}{2} >= 0$$
$$2*\frac{(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2}{2} >= 2*0$$
$$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 >= 0$$
So the above equation is zero when $a=b=c$

So the above inequality is proved

Comment: This duplicates the same [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64870/291201) posted 11 years ago. Just because you expanded it into a step-by-step doesn't make it different, or better.

Comment: I have done the equation in the forward manner. The answer that was posted was from the last equation to the first but it should be done in the matter above

Comment: Your answer is the same as the answer linked by dxiv. You are right, it should be done as you shown. But what you did is the same as the other, but without explaining it further.

Comment: @ishaant The order does not matter as long as each step is an equivalence. - because, by definition, it can be rewritten in the opposite order.  That is precisely why your answer is the same with the other answer.

Comment: Sorry if you think that this is duplicated. But I have solved it on my own and do not consider it duplicate

Answer (score 0):

From Cauchy-Schwarz

$ab+bc+ac=\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{b^2}+\sqrt{b^2}\sqrt{c^2}+\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{c^2} \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

Moving on;

$ab+bc+ac \leq a^2+b^2+c^2$

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Obtained
$$\sum a^{2}- \sum ab= \left ( c+ a- 2b \right )^{2}+ 3\left ( a- b \right )\left ( b- c \right )$$
by assuming $b:=\mathsf{med}\left ( a, b, c \right ).$

Comment: Note that the above equality is true even if $b$ is not the median. Of course, choosing $b$ to be the median is what gives you that the second term is also non-negative.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani that's because $a, b, c$ have the same role in the symmetric inequality.

Comment: I don't understand what you're replying to (when you say, "that's because..."). I didn't have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Obtained
$$\sum a^{2}- \sum ab= \sum a\left ( a- b \right )\geq 0$$
by assuming $a\geq b\geq 0\geq c.$