# Prove that $xy+yz+zx \leq x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $xy+yz+zx \leq  x^2+y^2+z^2$ . Hint: Use $\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}$

First I tried using the hint by setting $a=x$ and $b=y+z$, however this results in the inequality:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \geq 2xy-2yz+2zx $$
which isn't quite the same thing.

Then I tried starting with what we're trying to prove (to hopefully end up with a true statement), but then I get to this:
$$(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3(xy+yz+zx)$$
and then I can't see what to do next.

This question is supposed to be straight forward, which is why I'm thinking there might be something wrong with it. Or I'm dumb.

As you can see I tagged this with Proof-strategy, so please don't bother writing down a full proof, just a few observations or hints are enough.

Comment: A minor point: The Hint should be $\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}$

Comment: Oh yeah woops, my mistake, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Set $a = x^2$, $b= y^2$ first. You get $x^2+y^2 \ge 2xy$ (by the Hint). Do so for other $y,z$ and $z,x$ and add the three inequalities up :)

Comment: the variables need to be all non negative

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64868/how-to-prove-a2-b2-c2-ge-ab-bc-ca) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/64868).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} \geq xy 
$$
$$
\frac{y^2 + z^2}{2} \geq yz 
$$
$$
\frac{z^2 + x^2}{2} \geq zx
$$
Now add these 3 inequalities side by side.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Use $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative using complex numbers.

Let
$$
\phi = -\tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{i} \sqrt{3}.
$$
Write
$$
\psi = x + \phi y + \phi^* z.
$$

As we have
$$
\psi \psi* \ge 0,
$$
we get
$$
\big( x + \phi y + \phi^* z \big) \big( x + \phi y + \phi^* z \big)^* \ge 0.
$$

Whence
$$
x^2 + \big(\phi^*\phi\big) y^2 + \big(\phi^*\phi\big) z^2
+ \big(\phi^* + \phi \big) x y + \big(\phi^* + \phi \big) y z
+ \big(\phi^* + \phi \big) z x.
$$

But
$$
\phi^*\phi = 1, \hspace{2em} \phi^* + \phi = -1.
$$

So we obtain
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx \ge 0.
$$

Comment: Oh wow, very creative! Also 'whence'! I'll definitely try your approach the next time I'm solving something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Notice

$$ x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy $$

$$ y^2 + z^2 \geq 2yz $$

$$ z^2 + x^2 \geq  2 zx $$

Implies

$$ 2x^2 + 2 y^2 + 2 z^2 \geq 2xy + 2yz  + 2zx $$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \geq xy \\
\frac{z^2+y^2}{2} \geq yz \\
\frac{x^2+z^2}{2} \geq xz
\end{eqnarray*}
Adding them up we get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple problem but here is one way to do it following hint:
$$
xy\leq|xy|=\sqrt{x^2y^2}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\implies xy\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}.
$$
The inequality $\sqrt{x^2y^2}\leq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ is where you use the hint. Now repeat these steps 2 more time: one for the pair $\{y,z\}$ and another for $\{z,x\}$. It remains then to add the three results.