# If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$, $x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48, xy+4yz+2zx=24$, then find $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48$ and $xy+4yz+2zx=24$, then find $x^2+y^2+z^2$.

I can find the answer if I find the value of $x+y+z$ and $xy+yz+zx$. But I don't know how to do that. I found that $$(x+2y+4z)^2=144 \implies x+2y+4z=±12$$
But I can't progress after this.

Comment: $xy+4z+2zx=24$, are you sure?

Comment: @s1mple From the context follows that it's $xy+4yz+2zx=24.$ See please better the Sujal's attempts.

Comment: @s1mple Sorry, I tend to make typos when I'm typing on a phone. So unfortunately your answer will be wrong. But I take the blame for that.

Comment: @SujalMotagi it's correct, i used what Michael told me. Just check once again.

Comment: Oh I'll check it out then.

Comment: @s1mple Yeah, I did, it was helpful. I know it's not in your answer, but what does (1,1,1) || (x, 2y, 4z) mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48 \cdots Eq.(1),\;\; xy+4yz+2zx=24 \cdots Eq.(2)$

From (1), $x^2+(2y)^2+(4z)^2=48 \cdots Eq.(3)$

$(2)\times4 \implies 4xy+16zy+8zx=96\cdots Eq.(4) $

$2\times Eq.(3)-Eq.(4)\implies 2[x^2+(2y)^2+(4z)^2]-2[2xy+8zy+4zx]=0 \implies (x-2y)^2+(2y-4z)^2+(x-4z)^2=0
\implies x=2y=4z.$

Now,
$xy+4zy+2zx=24 \implies 3x^2=48\implies x^2=16
$.

Now, $x=4$, then $y=2,z=1$.

$\implies x^2+y^2+z^2=21$.

You will get the same answer even if you take $x=-4$.

Answer (score 2):

Now, by C-S $$144=3\cdot48=(1+1+1)(x^2+4y^2+16z^2)\geq(x+2y+4z)^2=144,$$
where the equality occurs for $$(1,1,1)||(x,2y,4z),$$
which gives  $$(x,y,z)=(4,2,1)$$ or
$$(x,y,z)=(-4,-2,-1)$$ and $$x^2+y^2+z^2=21.$$

Comment: You're good at inequalities. This is a brilliant answer.

Comment: Sorry but what does (1,1,1)||(x,2y,4z) mean? I don't know the notation.

Comment: I never expected an inequality in this question.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg, why did you think of using inequalities? I want to improve my problem solving skills so I want to know how you thought of it.

Comment: @Sujal Motagi  Your problem just looks for using C-S...

Comment: @Sujal Motagi $(1,1,1)||(x,2y,4z)$ says that a vector $(1,1,1)$ is parallel to the vector $(x,2y,4z)$, which says that there is $\lambda,$ for which  $\lambda(1,1,1)=(x,2y,4z).$

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't know much about vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=x$, $b:=2y$, and $c:=4z$.  Then,
$$\begin{align}a^2+b^2+c^2&=x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48=2\cdot 24\\&=2\cdot(xy+4yz+2zx)=bc+ca+ab\,.\end{align}$$
It is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64868/how-to-prove-a2-b2-c2-ge-ab-bc-ca) that, for real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=bc+ca+ab$ if and only if $a=b=c$.  That is, $$x=2y=4z\,.$$
Since $x^2+4y^2+16z^2=48$, we get $$(x,y,z)=\pm(4,2,1)\,.$$
That is,
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=16+4+1=21\,.$$

Comment: I didn't know about the property you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

$$0 = x^2 + 4 y^2 + 16 z^2 - 2 (4yz + 2zx + xy) = (x-y-2z)^2 + 3 (y-2z)^2  $$
So, as noted $y = 2z$  and $x = y+2z = 4z,$ so
$$ 48 = x^2 + 4 y^2 + 16 z^2 = 16 z^2 + 16 z^2 + 16 z^2 = 48 z^2 $$
and $z = \pm 1.$